# How to change chassis description?

Tags: juniper

I would like to change chassis description. Command show chassis hardware display the list of all hardware (also chassis) with interesting parameters (also description). It's possible to change eg. Chassis description? Below example:

```
user@host> show chassis hardware
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                E1372             MX10-T
Midplane         REV 01   711-038211   YF5285            MX10-T
PEM 0            Rev 04   740-028288   VB01678           AC Power Entry Module
Routing Engine            BUILTIN      BUILTIN           Routing Engine
TFEB 0                    BUILTIN      BUILTIN           Forwarding Engine Processor
  QXM 0          REV 05   711-028408   ZA9053            MPC QXM
FPC 0                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           MPC BUILTIN
  MIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 10GE XFP
    PIC 0                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 10GE XFP
FPC 1                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           MPC BUILTIN
  MIC 0          REV 24   750-028392   YX9436            3D 20x 1GE(LAN) SFP
    PIC 0                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           10x 1GE(LAN) SFP
      Xcvr 0     REV 01   740-031851   AM1107SUFQW       SFP-SX
    PIC 1                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           10x 1GE(LAN) SFP
Fan Tray       

                                      Fan Tray
```

I cannot find an answer in Juniper decumentation and technical forums. I have only simulator of Juniper on GNS3 environment, which don't contain real hardware. Thus I cannot check in on real device. I suspect that this parameter is not editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a description you can configure in JUNOS, it's a description which type of hardware it is. So you're using a GNS3 image (if that's the correct term, I'm not familiar with GNS3) which emulates a MX10-T.

Comment: Yes I'm using GNS3 image of junos software. But I would like to know if on real phisical device is possible to change this parameter?

Comment: No, as a I said you cannot change this. It's a description of a hardware component.